# Changing integration order and limits

Tags: calculus, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

My teacher wrote the following on the board yesterday

$$
\int_A^B\int_A^u{f''(v)dvdu} = \int_A^B\int_v^B{f''(v)dudv}
$$

He mentioned that it follows straightforwardly from Fubini's theorem, however, it is not intuitively clear to me that the two integrals are the same.

Could someone shed some light on the above?

Comment: You might want to try sketch out the integration region first. This will give you a visual way to understand both representations.

Comment: @KenHung The LHS is a triangle with base $A$ to $B$ and height $A$ to $u$. But what about the RHS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following geometric meaning:

$${}{}$$
[image]

$${}{}{}$$

The vertical axis is $\;v\;$ , the horizontal one is $\;u\;$ (the thin black lines meeting at the origin $\;0\,$), the green horizontal line is $\;v=A\;$ and the gray thin horizontal line where it is written $\;2\;$ is $\;v=B\;$ . And thus the gray wide vertical line is $\;x=A\;$ and the wide black vertical line is $\;u=B\;$, and of course the red line is $\;v=u\;$ .

Your integration domain is the red-green-black triangle, so if you change the integration order you get that $\;u\;$ runs from $\;u=A\;$ to $\;u=B\;$, whereas $\;v\;$ runs from $\;v=u\;$ to $\;v= b\;$ , which is precisely what is written in your question...

Comment: So do I understand correctly that the integration-area of the RHS is a triangle with the same area, but the triangle is basically the red-green-black triangle mirrored about the $v=u$-line?

Comment: @TylerD Exactly so: mirrored orthogonally thru the $\;u=v\;$ line. Nice.

Comment: (+1) I think graphically is the best way to understand limits